# iphone sdk - how do i do this if else checking logic. checking an NSMutableArray for a possible value against parsed xml

Tags: iphone

EDIT*
hi guys , lets say i have an array with 5 Strings = "1","2","3","4","5".
Im also doing parsing of xml. So how do i check whether a parse xml value is the same value of either one of the objects IN the array?

Comment: you mean your array contains 5 strings object, 5 NSNumber object or 5 integer?

Comment: tho i can just do the intValue method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved * i put them in a for loop to, looping through each array.value and making a root (if else) that checks whether the value in the array is equal to the parsed xml value